# Encountering Failure when Attempting to Clone a Private Bitbucket Repository in EC2 Userdata Script

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am using an Ubuntu environment on an AWS EC2 instance to perform a git clone.
I put the private key in $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.

```
chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T git@bitbucket.org
git clone -b dev git@bitbucket.org:xxx/yyy.git
```

when i do nano `nano /var/log/cloud-init-output.log`
the last few lines displayed

```
Computing checksum with sha256sum
Checksums matched!
Now using node v16.20.2 (npm v8.19.4)
Creating default alias: default -> 16.20.2 (-> v16.20.2 *)
Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
authenticated via ssh key.

You can use git to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
Cloud-init v. 23.2.2-0ubuntu0~22.04.1 finished at Tue, 09 Jan 2024 09:45:27 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2Local.  Up 123.36 seconds
```

I think i successfully connected to Bitbucket but for some reasons i failed doing git clone.

When I copy my entire script to the EC2 console, the git clone command successfully clones the repository. However, when I embed the same script into the EC2 userdata script, it fails.

Comment: Does your user data script have `set -e` or `-e` on the `#!bash` line?  If so, then the failure from the ssh command will cause the script to exit.

Comment: no i dont have set -e , my setting is like  #!/bin/bash sudo -u ubuntu -i <<'EOF'